# Facebook comment box on my website

Tags: facebook, comments, height

I tried to use the Facebook comment box on my site. I included the Javascript SDK in the `<body>` tag, and then this code:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js= d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/hu_HU/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=439919819448461"
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

When I use this, all my browsers(Firefox, Chrome) are loading it but finally it won't be displayed. When I change it to this:

```html
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

It now works, but there is another error: when It displays the box, the box's height is fixed, it doesn't extend with comments ( no matter, how I change the value of "data-num-posts="10">"), and at the bottom there is no button, what says: "View XYZ more". The only options to scroll is to drag with the mouse. It won't work in Dreamweaver or antenna web design studio, but others comment boxes works on my browser. I deleted all cookie and I don't have any other idea.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry.You just need to put this code under a selector with div tag.After that adjust the div selector's width and height.Suitably use height as auto and give a min-width to it.Inside  and  just put in the following code.It works well.

`< fb:comments href="http://example.com/page" num_posts="10" width="700px" style="position:relative;display:block;">`

Answer (score 0):

> `<div id="fb-root"></div>`
>
> `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>`
>
> `<div id="id_name">
>        <fb:comments href="`http://example.com/page`" num_posts="10" width="700px" style="position:relative;display:block;">
>        </fb:comments`>
>   `